# Is there a way to grep gzipped content in hdfs without extracting it?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm looking for a way to `zgrep` `hdfs` files

something like:

```
hadoop fs -zcat hdfs://myfile.gz | grep "hi"
```

or

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://myfile.gz | zgrep "hi"
```

it does not really work for me is there anyway to achieve that with command line?

Comment: gzip is a simple linear compressor, it doesn't contain any index or similar. Thus AFAIK what you want is impossible, just as in the case of hadoop or in any other settings.

Comment: if i have a single gzip file in hdfs i could have expected "hadoop fs" to be able to uncompress it for me and do the `zless` / `zcat` for me... instead i need to do this work by myself...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*zless/zcat/zgrep* are just shell wrappers that make *gzip* output the decompressed data to stdout.  To do what you want, you'll just have to write a wrapper around the *hadoop fs* commands.

Aside:  The reason this probably didn't work for you is that you're missing an additional slash in your hdfs URI.

You wrote:

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://myfile.gz | zgrep "hi"
```

This attempts to contact the host or cluster called *myfile.gz*.  What you really want is either *hdfs:///myfile.gz* or (assuming your config files are set up correctly), just *myfile.gz*, which the hadoop command should prepend with the correct cluster/namenode path defined by *fs.defaultFS*.

The following works for me.

```
$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs:///user/hcoyote/foo.gz
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hcoyote users    5184637 2015-02-20 12:17 hdfs:///user/hcoyote/foo.gz

$ hadoop fs -cat hdfs:///user/hcoyote/foo.gz | gzip -c -d | grep -c Authorization
425893

$ hadoop fs -cat hdfs:///user/hcoyote/foo.gz | zgrep -c Authorization
425893
```

Answer (score 6):

This command-line will automatically find the right decompressor for any simple text file and print the uncompressed data to standard output:

```
hadoop fs -text hdfs:///path/to/file [hdfs:///path/to/another/file]
```

I have used this for .snappy & .gz files. It probably works for .lzo and .bz2 files.

This is an important feature because Hadoop uses a custom file format for Snappy files. This is the only direct way to uncompress a Hadoop-created Snappy file. There is no command-line 'unsnappy' command like there is for the other compressors. I also don't know of any direct command that creates one. I've only created them as Hive table data.

Note: `hadoop fs -text` is single-threaded and runs the decompression on the machine where you run the command.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use hdfs fuse mounts.. so can use almost any regular Unix commands (some of the commands may not work as hdfs is not POSIX-compliant filesystem).

gunzip/zcat

```
$ gunzip /hdfs_mount/dir1/somefile.gz 
$ grep hi /hdfs_mount/dir1/somefile.gz
```

works just fine on hdfs fuse mounts. And faster to type too :) , easier to read if e.g. you want to script that.

To mount hadoop as a "regular" filesystem:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_28.html